# Google Cloud Platform: Cloud Monitoring API errors showing in metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I seem to be getting around 30% errors related to:

```
google.monitoring.v3.MetricService.CreateTimeSeries
```

In The Cloud Monitoring API Metrics dash.

Any idea what could be causing this? As far as I know I am using the default install, having only at one time manually installed StackDriver on Debian 9. I have no idea how to interrogate the cause of these errors and where to do so in order to trace the issue.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you have reason to believe these errors are a problem, I wouldn't bother investigating them on their own.
2. You can look at the logs in your project to get error details.